# TypeScript like type in Swift

Tags: swift, typescript

I'm just wondering if we can do something like this (TypeScript) in Swift ?

```js
enum SomeEnum {
    a, b, c, d
}

const someFunction = (param: SomeEnum.a | SomeEnum.b) => {



}

const anotherFunction = () => {
    // this gives me a warning 
    someFunction(SomeEnum.c)
}
```

Basically, I have an `Enum` and but `someFunction` only accepts some parts of that Enum. So when you use that function it gives you a warning. Can we do something similar in Swift ? I don't want to create new Enum type just to do this ...

Comment: I'm afraid not. The cases of an enum don't define their own types, so there's no way to use them in the type system, at all. Depending on the usecase, the closest solution I can think of is a group of struct which conform to a common protocol (which replaces `SomeEnum`), and only `a` and `b` conform to a second protocol, which you use as the input to your function

Comment: I think you can write a [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) rule for this, if it's just looking for `someFunction(SomeEnum.c)`.

Comment: you can add a precondition like `precondition(param == .a || param == .b, "SomeEnum must be equal to a or b")`

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes but that's not a compile warning, it's a runtime crash.